# Variable is not displaying in input box | Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a calculator using buttons to display numbers and operations in the input box. However, the variable `nums` wont display

Heres the code:

```js
function display(clicked_id) {
  var nums = document.getElementById("display_area").value;
  nums = nums + document.getElementById(clicked_id).value;
  document.getElementById("display_area") === nums;
}

function calculate() {
  var e = eval(document.getElementById("display_area").value);
  document.getElementById("display_area") === e;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table border="1" style="width:182px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="display_area" style="width:164px;text-align:right">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id="1" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="1">1</button>
        <button id="2" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="2">2</button>
        <button id="3" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="3">3</button>
        <button id="+" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="+">+</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id="4" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="4">4</button>
        <button id="5" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="5">5</button>
        <button id="6" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="6">6</button>
        <button id="-" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="-">-</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id="7" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="7">7</button>
        <button id="8" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="8">8</button>
        <button id="9" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="9">9</button>
        <button id="x" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="x">x</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button id="." style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value=".">.</button>
        <button id="0" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="0">0</button>
        <button id="=" style="width:40px" onclick="calculate()" value="=">=</button>
        <button id="/" style="width:40px" onclick="display(this.id)" value="/">/</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

After a few tests I think that this line is the problem:

`document.getElementById("display_area") === nums;`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have try textContent or innerHTML?

For example:
 document.getElementById("display_area").textComtent= nums;

Comment: @YORS Typo: `textComtent`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are updating content inside `input`, using `document.getElementById("display_area").setAttribute("value", nums);` might be more appropriate as the method sets attribute value.

I haven't fixed other logic issue, but you can try it in the sandbox, the value can be rendered now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <table border="1" style="width: 182px">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="display_area"
              style="width: 164px; text-align: right"
              value=""
            ></input>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button
              id="1"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="1"
            >
              1
            </button>
            <button
              id="2"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="2"
            >
              2
            </button>
            <button
              id="3"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="3"
            >
              3
            </button>
            <button
              id="+"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="+"
            >
              +
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button
              id="4"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="4"
            >
              4
            </button>
            <button
              id="5"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="5"
            >
              5
            </button>
            <button
              id="6"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="6"
            >
              6
            </button>
            <button
              id="-"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="-"
            >
              -
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button
              id="7"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="7"
            >
              7
            </button>
            <button
              id="8"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="8"
            >
              8
            </button>
            <button
              id="9"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="9"
            >
              9
            </button>
            <button
              id="x"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="x"
            >
              x
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <button
              id="."
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="."
            >
              .
            </button>
            <button
              id="0"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="0"
            >
              0
            </button>
            <button id="=" style="width: 40px" onclick="calculate()" value="=">
              =
            </button>
            <button
              id="/"
              style="width: 40px"
              onclick="display(this.id)"
              value="/"
            >
              /
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <script>
        function display(clicked_id) {
          var nums = document.getElementById("display_area").value;
          nums = nums + document.getElementById(clicked_id).value;
          document.getElementById("display_area").setAttribute("value", nums);
        }
        function calculate() {
          var e = eval(document.getElementById("display_area").value);
          document.getElementById("display_area") === e;
        }
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("display_area") === nums;` This line of code is for comparing values not displaying them. To achieve what you want, use `.innerHTML`.
your code will become `document.getElementById("display_area").innerHTML = nums;`

Comment: `.innerHTML` should be avoided whenever possible (which is almost all the time) as it has security and performance implications. `.textContent` should be used instead, especially since there is no HTML in `nums`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right the problem is in the line

```
document.getElementById("display_area") === nums;
```

Replace it  with:

```
document.getElementById("display_area").innerHTML = nums;
```

Comment: You have a typo in your answer `,` instead of `.`.  Also, `.innerHTML` should be avoided whenever possible (which is almost all the time) as it has security and performance implications. `.textContent` should be used instead, especially since there is no HTML in `nums`.

Comment: Sorry, Now Fixed.

Comment: Ok, if you don't want to use innerHTML than what you think about using innerText? It is an input field, both work fine for me.

Comment: .innerText is not standard although it works everywhere for legacy reasons. .textContent is the standard and should be favored.